# Guitar tuning with digital tuner

Tags: scales, acoustic-guitar, tuning

I am trying to tune my Washburn acoustic using a Stagg T-UC digital tuner, could use some help please

Manual for my tuner can be found here:
http://www.globalcube.net/clients/staggmusicv2/content/medias/download/SUPPORT/USERMANUELS/TunerMetronome/TUC.pdf

Q: the tuner gives me the option to set the Scale to Bb, Eb, C or F - what do these mean, and which one should I select for standard tuning?

Fyi, I have the tuner set to 440 Hz

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the key sentence:

*This device allows a large variety of instruments to be tuned: woodwinds, brass, stringed instruments, etc.*

That is, it allows instruments that are not concert pitch to be tuned in their native key. So, a trumpet would set it to `Bb`, a french horn to `F`, and an alto sax to `Eb`.

Guitar is a concert pitch instrument, so it should be set to `C`.